# Mrs. Malaprop = Malapropism - any other examples

Tags: etymology

Are there other literary examples where-in a character or subject eventually morphed into descriptive verb/genre?

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100242/words-based-on-the-names-of-gods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for cases in which "a character or subject eventually morphed into descriptive verb/genre". Other answerers have assumed you mean just a fictional character (and not a subject, by which, to be honest, I don't know what you mean), and I'll do the same. They've also not restricted to descriptive verbs and genres, suggesting *milquetoast* and *quixotic*, so I, too, won't so restrict.

Some they haven't mentioned are [*Achillean*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Achillean), *aphrodisiac*, [*argonaut*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/argonaut), *bacchanalia*, [*Mickey Mouse*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mickey_Mouse#Adjective), *Falstaffian*, [*Ichabod*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ichabod), [*Moses basket*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Moses_basket), *Oedipus complex*, *oedipal*, *Electra complex*, *Timonism*, and [*sword of Damocles*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sword_of_Damocles).

Answer (score 4):

We seem to be talking about eponymous terms derived from fictional characters?  Four of the most famous of those would have to be *quixotic*, *faustian*, *gargantuan*, and *holmesian*.  Another may be *chauvinism*, but it's unclear whether Nicolas Chauvin was a real person.

Evidently *pecksniffian* had some currency at some point, but seems to have declined in popularity.  Lamentably similar is *panglossian*.

Comment: John Curtis Holmes?  How did he die - he overcame himself?

Comment: @ArthurRex: Sherlock Holmes.

Answer (score 3):

"Spoonerism" - after the Rev. Spooner, who reputedly continually interchanged the first letters/sounds of words. "Today we'll learn how to build a turdy stable" - (a Sturdy Table).

Well, if we're limiting ourselves to fictitious persons (not that I see that in the question), I suppose "Bushism" is out. Too bad.

Comment: Rev. Spooner was a real person.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorites is *milquetoast*, describing a timid, submissive person. It comes from the name of a cartoon character, Caspar Milquetoast, created by H. T. Webster in 1924.

There's also *Faustian*, to describe a bargain in which one trades their moral integrity for material gains.

*Pandemonium* came from *Paradise Lost*. We now associate it with mayhem and discord. Milton conceived of it as the name of the place where demons live.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [*mondegreen*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) may be another example of a term derived from a fictional character. The caveat is that it's not derived from an *actual* fictional character, but instead from a character by the name of Lady Mondegreen that Sylvia Wright *thought* was in [a poem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bonny_Earl_O%27Moray) due to the mishearing of the line *"laid him on the green"*.

Answer (score 1):

"Sati" was the name of a Hindu goddess, which turned into a term for a widow killing herself at her husband's funeral pyre.

If you have time to waste, TV Tropes' neologism page would have an example of works of literature creating new terms. <s>It'd list not just neologisms based on character names, but other neologisms such as "thought police", however.</s>

**Edit**: Not a single example - people haven't spent enough time on the web site!

Answer (score 1):

I think the American version of 'malapropisms' is 'Archie Bunkerisms'.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to any imagery that is absurd, bizarre, impossible to construct, or self-referential, I like the home-grown term *Escheresque* (after M. C. Escher).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget Jeremiad or picaresque (from Picarillo de Tormes).