# Words based on the names of gods

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, vocabulary, proper-nouns, religion

While the word [christen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/christen) means "to baptise" or "to make Christian", in another sense, it has shed its religious connotations to simply mean "to name" or even "use for the first time". Is there any other word which is based on the **name** (or epithet) of a *god* or *prophet*, (or possibly some other *significant* religious figure) with *at least one of its definitions devoid of religious connotations*?

[Words like *good* (from *god* which is too generic), *august* (from *Augustus*, a senate-approved god), and other similarly borderline cases are to be excused.]

**Edit:** I'm not looking for *synonyms* of the word *christen* or words in common usage which come from religion. They have to be based on *names*.

Comment: Name? Are you limiting this to names of various gods that have derivatives that are not religious anymore?

Comment: 'Boston Brahmin'. 'Good-bye' (from "God be with you"). An minced oath based on 'God' or 'Jesus': goldurn, jeez.

Comment: @Mitch hmm, I'm not sure that Brahmin counts. "Jeez" is simply taking the lord's name in vain, yes? :) Jon Hanna's got a number of hits; I hadn't taken the bewildering array of the Greek/Roman pantheon into sufficient consideration when formulating this question.

Comment: Why doesn't 'Brahmin' not count? It's from a religious name, and it has no religious connotation in that context. Why is beng 'in vain' not a fit? It's a religious name (modified) with no religious connotation. What more criteria do you have that exclude these?

Comment: @Mitch I've added in Brahmin as coming from the god, Brahma. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a name for this? Because I don't understand the single-word-request tag here.

Comment: Days of the week? Woden's-day, Thor's-day, etc.

Comment: @KitFox The [tag:word-requests] tag appears to be a synonym of the [tag:single-word-request] tag.

Comment: Out of curiosity, _why_ exactly are you looking for such words with such specific criteria?

Comment: @Mitch I'm helping somebody with the character set-up for a card game based on religion.

Comment: What? You crowd sourced us? Well played!

Comment: @coleopterist Not Brahma but Brahman. Brahman is God, the totality of the universe; Brahma is one of his many facets, the Deva who created the world.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit: This first bit was after my not grokking the question. I'm leaving it anyway. Proper answer follows

---

*Christen* does not mean "to make Christian", it means "to anoint with oil", which is part of the Christian naming rite. (*Christ* is from the same root, meaning "anointed one").

*Sain* is sometimes used of people being named in religious rites without it being specific to any particular religion, and is popular as such in some Neopagan circles (pardon the pun), though ironically this in origin was specifically Christian, since it refers to the sign of the cross being made and is cognate with *sign*.

*Clerk* originally meant a member of the clergy (where we would now use *cleric* that was deliberately introduced to avoid confusion). It comes from a time when being literate and being clergy was essentially one and the same within Christendom, and indeed being literate remained the legal definition of clergy (saving you from execution for some crimes) well after this was no longer the case.

(Incidentally, while the Old English for both *god* and *good* was spelt *god*, these were two heteronyms, pronounced differently and coming from different roots. It wouldn't even have made much sense to say "God is good" at the time, as it didn't have the absolute sense it has now — if you'd said "God is good" people would have wondered what you were saying He was good for.)

---

Now for the actual answer to the question intended:

Some adjectives from the names of gods, that no longer refer solely to the gods in question:

*Jovial*, *martial*, *saturnine*, *mercurial*, *erotic*, *anterotic* (whether this is formed as not-erotic or from Anteros is unclear), *chaotic*.

The prefix *geo-* is from Gaia, and *chrono-* from Chronos.

Edit: Some more:

*Hermaphrodite*, *dionysian*, *cereal*, *hygiene*, *echo*, *venereal*, *museum*, *herculean*, *volcano*, *nemesis*, *morphine* & *helium*.

If we allow heroes, monsters, etc. as well as gods:

*Oedipal*, *sisyphean*, *narcissist*, *siren*, *mentor* and finally *titanic* if we allow a group of gods, as well individuals.

Some uses of Christian figures as expletives have become detached from their origin, so while someone who says "god-damn" would know where it came from, someone might say *bloody* or *zounds* not knowing they come from "by Our Lady" and "God's wounds" respectively. ("Our Lady" is a title used as a name, so whether you choose to count that or not, I don't know).

Comment: Thank you. I was quoting Wiktionary :) I'm interested in words _like_ christen which stem from names of religious figures and yet also carry non-religious definitions. Please let me know if my question is unclear on this point.

Comment: Ah, I mis-read. I'm leaving *sain* since while I added it as an extra, it actually answers directly. I'm sure I can think of some others too.

Comment: _Sain_ appears to come from the Latin _signo_ for sign. I'm looking for words like _august_ which comes from the **name** of a Roman god named _Augustus_.

Comment: Ah, I can give you a few of those, all right.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a list including those in Jon's answer:

#### Christianity

- Judas

#### Greek

- Amuse
- [Aphrodisiac](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aphrodisiac): *Arousing or intensifying sexual desire* (from the goddess, *Aphrodite*)
- [Apollonian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apollonian): *Clear, harmonious, and restrained.* (from the god, *Apollo*)
- [Dionysian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dionysian): *wild, irrational, and undisciplined* (from the god, *Dionysus*)
- [Echo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/echo): *a reflected sound heard again from its originator* (from the nymph, *Echo*)
- Helium
- [Hermetic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hermetic): *Isolated, away from outside influence.* (from the god, *Hermes*)
- [Morphine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/morphine): *A crystalline alkaloid extracted from opium* (from the god, *Morpheus*)
- Muse
- [Narcissist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narcissist): *A vain person* (from *Narcissus*)
- [Nemesis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nemesis): *An archenemy* (from the goddess, *Nemesis*)
- Nymphomaniac
- [Odyssey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/odyssey): *a long arduous journey* (from the hero, *Odysseus*)
- [Panic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/panic): *Overpowering fright, often affecting groups of people or animals.* (from the Greek god, *Pan*)
- Panacea
- -phobia
- [Priapism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/priapism): *A painful and potentially harmful medical condition in which the erect penis (erection) does not return to its flaccid state* (from the god, *Priapus*)

#### Hindu

- [Brahmin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brahmin): *A social and cultural elite, especially in the New England region of the USA*. (from the name of God who is the universe, *Brahman*)
- [Juggernaut](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/juggernaut): *A literal or metaphorical force or object regarded as unstoppable, that will crush all in its path.* (from the god, *Jagannath*)

#### Judaism

- [Nimrod](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/odyssey): *An idiot* (from the "mighty hunter" *Nimrod* mentioned in Genesis)

#### Norse

- [Tuesday](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tuesday): *Day of the week* (from the god, *Tyr*)
- [Wednesday](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wednesday): *Day of the week* (from the god, *Odin*)
- [Thursday](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Thursday): *Day of the week* (from the god, *Thor*)
- [Friday](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Friday): *Day of the week* (from the goddess, *Freya*/*Frigg*)

#### Roman

- [Aurora](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aurora): *An atmospheric phenomenon created by charged particles from the sun striking the upper atmosphere* (from the goddess, *Aurora*)
- [Bacchanal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bacchanal): *Engaged in drunken revels; drunken and riotous or noisy.* (from the god, *Bacchus*)
- [Cereal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cereal): *A type of grass (such as wheat, rice or oats) cultivated for its edible grains.* (from the goddess, *Ceres*)
- Cupidity
- Fauna
- Flora
- [Herculean](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herculean): *Extraordinary (regarding size, power, might, etc.)* (from the hero/demigod, *Hercules*)
- Genius
- Janus
- [Jovial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jovial): *Merry; cheerful and good-humored.* (from the god, *Jupiter*)
- Liberty
- [Martial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/martial): *Of, relating to, or suggestive of war; warlike.* (from the god, *Mars*)
- [Mercurial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mercurial): *Volatile; erratic; unstable; flighty; fickle or changeable in temperament.* (from the god, *Mercury*)
- Plutocrat
- [Saturnine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saturnine): *gloomy, depressed, dull* (from the god, *Saturn*)
- [Saturday](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Saturday): *Day of the week* (from the god, *Saturn*)
- Solar
- [Sylvan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sylvan): *wooded* (from the god, *Silvanus*)
- Terra-firma
- Volcano
- Virtue

Answer (score 3):

In English, the verb *to christen* has a sense of 'to confer a name upon'. It's one of those rare non-dative bitransitive verbs. I.e, like *name* and *elect*, *christen* has **two** objects, neither of which is an indirect object:

- *They named the baby Jesús.*
- *We elected Mary president.*
- *I hereby christen this ship the* USS Fiscal Cliff.

The last sentence is a [Performative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance) use of *christen*, which may be the one sought.

**If** the person uttering that sentence is duly authorized, and if that speaker pronounces this utterance at the appropriate time and place (with the appropriate props and actions, as needed), **then** the speaker not only pronounces the utterance, but also, **in saying it** (see ["illocutionary act"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illocutionary_act)), the speaker causes the ship to be named the *USS Fiscal Cliff*, officially, on the record.

This is much like Christian baptism, though no font, faith, or fealty is implied. Names can be changed, after all, and this is a civil ritual.

Comment: Who are these famous parents? I thought only Mary and Joseph named the baby Jesus, apart from in prayers. :)

Comment: @tchrist since the spelling here is *Jesús*, there are indeed quite a few people of that name, not just the most famous ישוע or perhaps יְהוֹשֻׁעַ.